# How can I upload files to django from within AS3 Flash?

Tags: django, flash, actionscript-3, upload, file-upload

I need to build a file uploader in AS3 that is capable of uploading files into an authenticated django view which contains a form with a file upload input.

I have been working on this for an entire 7 days, all day.

After much digging, I have discovered that Adobe, in their infinite wisdom has disabled cookie headers from being sent from flash.  By default, django only accepts sessionid's via cookie, so I added a custom middleware that allows authentication via a sessionid POST var.  This has been tested, and is functional.

However, I still cannot upload, even with the sessionid in the POST.  When I do attempt an upload, the bytes seem to go up, and then for some reason, the upload fails.  Here is said response.

```
flash says selectHandler: name=douchetop.png URL=http://dev.citizengroove.com/upload/
progressHandler: name=douchetop.png bytesLoaded=32768 bytesTotal=139082
progressHandler: name=douchetop.png bytesLoaded=65536 bytesTotal=139082
progressHandler: name=douchetop.png bytesLoaded=98304 bytesTotal=139082
progressHandler: name=douchetop.png bytesLoaded=131072 bytesTotal=139082
progressHandler: name=douchetop.png bytesLoaded=139082 bytesTotal=139082
httpResponseStatusHandler: [HTTPStatusEvent type="httpStatus" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 status=500]
httpStatusHandler: [HTTPStatusEvent type="httpStatus" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 status=500]
flash says: ioErrorHandler: Error #2038: File I/O Error. URL: http://dev.citizengroove.com/upload/
```

Please, please, please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is, but I might be able to give you some advice to help you work through this.

Have you tried uploading the file via curl?

```
curl http://dev.citizengroove.com/upload/ -d <Post Data> -T douchetop.png
```

Then, based on what that hands back to you, you might be able to debug this easier assuming that the problem is within django and not flash. If nothing else you will know which half of this is having the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not sure what the problem is, but I hope I can fling some helpful details your way. From what I can figure, your sending the data, but cannot reconstruct it on Django's end.

For `HttpRequest.FILES`, the [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) say: "Note that FILES will only contain data if the request method was POST and the `<form>` that posted to the request had enctype="multipart/form-data". Otherwise, FILES will be a blank dictionary-like object."

If your not posting the form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, you'll have to reconstruct the file from `request.raw_post_data`. This is explained by @theivviax [here](http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=50).

He initially wrote this comment when using [Pluploads](http://www.plupload.com/), which does have support for a flash backend for uploading large files over HTTP. It's licensed under GPLv2, perhaps you can take a peek at their docs or sources.